# Cannot pass audio source to ngAudio inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of data in my controller, including a string which is the source of a sound file. What I need to do is read the array and show it in a ng-repeat. I have a button which have to play the sound of each element of the array.

The source is a string, but when I pass it to ngAudio, it searches for a source like> http://localhost:8100/%7B%7Banimal.audio%7D%7D, so it never finds the file to play it

I've thought of having another controller which will recieve the value of the source, once it is calling by ng-repeat, but that doesn't look good for me. Is there a way to archieve this?

this is my code:

```
//controller

.controller('GranjaController', function($scope) {
  $scope.animals = [
    { name: 'Vaca', id: 1, img: "img/granja/vaca.png", kname: "Wakax", audio: "sounds/vaca.mp3" },
    { name: 'Caballo', id: 2, img: "img/granja/caballo.png", kname: "Kej" , audio: "sounds/caballo.mp3" }
  ];
})



//index.html

<ion-item ng-repeat="animal in animals" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
    <img ng-src="{{animal.img}}" />
    {{animal.name}}
    <button ng-audio= "{{animal.audio}}" volume="0.5" start="0.2">Click me</button>
    <button ng-audio= "sounds/granja/vaca.mp3" volume="0.5" start="0.2">Click me</button>
</ion-item>
```

The first button never reach a file, because ngAudio receives a weird string, the second button works perfectly although is the same string I have in the array.
As the documentation of ngAudio says: "**ngAudio: Takes a string and creates a new object with ngAudio.load()**"
Then why it doesn't work?

---

**UPDATE**

I made it work by using the load() method inside the controller, as [@jami0821](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215966/jami0821) pointed me. This is my final code:

```
//controller

.controller('GranjaController', function($scope, ngAudio) {
  $scope.animals = [
    { name: 'Vaca', id: 1, img: "img/granja/vaca.png", kname: "Wakax", audio: ngAudio.load("sounds/granja/vaca.mp3") },
    { name: 'Caballo', id: 2, img: "img/granja/caballo.png", kname: "Kej" , audio: ngAudio.load("sounds/granja/caballo.mp3") }
  ];
})


//index.html
<ion-item ng-repeat="animal in animals" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
    <img ng-src="{{animal.img}}" />
    {{animal.name}}
    <button ng-click="animal.audio.play()">Click me</button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: could you try `ng-attrs-ng-audio= "{{animal.audio}}"`

Comment: doesn't work. It doesn't even show the request of the file in the console

Comment: @PankajParkar no. with ng-audio shows a 404 error, but ng-attrs-ng-audio doesn't even request the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Audio is loaded through the `load` method of the ngAudio service:

```
angular.module('yourModule',['ngAudio'])
.controller("yourController",function($scope,ngAudio){
    $scope.sound = ngAudio.load("sounds/mySound.mp3"); // returns NgAudioObject
})
```

So may want to try modifying your controller to include the `ngAudio` dependency as well as the `load` method.

Source: https://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/docs

Comment: I'm accesing the view by a route attached to a controller, and still not working

Comment: And you've corrected the spacing to: `ng-audio="{{animal.audio}}"`

Comment: yes, but nothing changed. Seems that ngAudio is reading the diretive as plain text

Comment: Have you applied the `load` method as described under the **Usage** section of the [docs](https://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/docs)?

Comment: it works! I had to change the button to: 
`<button ng-click="animal.audio.play()">Click me</button>`